# Sharepoint Attendees without a Workspace for Calendar Event

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I am wondering if it is possible to have a custom form in Sharepoint 2010 where I am able to add/edit a calendar event and access the attendees list that is normally visible on the workspace page.

I assume that perhaps I need to at least hard code a workspace to be selected as I believe attendees need to be assigned to a workspace.

Open to suggestions as I'm new to Sharepoint but seems crazy having to create or link to a workplace for each event.

Greatly appreciate any help.

Comment: This should be migrated to SharePoint.SE

Answer (score 3):

@WashBurn not sure if this what you are looking for.  Goto your calendar - list settings. goto the "Content Types" section.  click the content type...should be event.  from there click "Add from existing site content types " and attendees should be in there.  hope that helps!

Answer (score 2):

There is a simple (unfortunately not intuitive) way to achieve what you are trying to do.

1. click on list settings for your calendar list. You will see about half way down a section called content types.

![enter image description here][1]

2. Click on the event content type (which should be there by default.
3. this takes you to another similar screen where you can simply add the attendees column.

Once you know that attendees are part of an event it is then intuitive.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

This is one of many nasty little things that come up when you try to build your meeting management on SharePoint. Other very common problems include integration with any e-mail client, first of all Outlook but not only, sending meeting requests from SharePoint and handling the respoded attendee's status... 
The SharePoint calendar e-mail extension is a third party solution that might solve your problem.

Here is the link: http://www.sapiens.at/en/products/pages/sharepoint-calendar-e-mail-extension-3.0.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Every SharePoint list (wether it's document library, calendar, lnks or custom list) have both a Create Form, Edit Form and a Delete Form. Each of which you through SharePoint designer can create your own custom versions of, in your case, this is needed to edit a Calendar List item with its associates/attachments.

[Read one of Microsoft's own guides on how, here](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-designer-help/create-a-custom-list-form-HA010119111.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for the reply Ziga. I have gotten this far but was unable to determine how to add the Attendee control as I was unable to find it in the Sharepoint Designer. Even then, I don't think it will be a simple case of dropping it onto the page.

Comment: @Washburn -- I'm not sure if the Attendee control is a webpart, but if it is, it can easily be inserted. You do this by entering the list through SPD, then edit one of the forms in Advanced Mode. In the top you select the tab **Insert** then in the Actionbar you click **Web Part** and there you find the Attendee controller and insert it where in the form you'd like it to be.

Answer (score 0):

Although this is a very old post, i just ran into the same issue and figured out a way to solve this issue.

Simply go into the Content Type 'Event' and add the Column 'Attendees' :)

Then you can also use the attendees as input for a workflow, e.g. to notify them on Event creation/update. i attached two Screenshots to show how you can do that using SharePoint designer!

[image: Get Event attendees as EMail Receipients]

With this phrase you can add the Link to the Event into the Mail Body:

```
[%Workflow Context:Current Item URL%]
```

Hope that helps other people in the future.

Answer (score 0):

I believe I have the solution we are all looking for.

1. Create a standard event calendar (the one that does not have attendees)
2. Add the 'Schedule and Reservations' content type to the calendar from the list settings page
3. Modify the 'Calendar' view so the filters read

attendees is equal to me

OR

attendees is equal to

The second entry is completely empty but allows SP to match for no attendees
You can add more columns with OR statements if you need to be sorting based on additional groups

This worked for my needs, hope it works for everyone else